# BindException from jetty on Unused Port

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, gretty

tl;dr: BindException, checked netstat and nothing is running any of the ports gretty is told to grab. I'm on FreeBSD if that makes any difference, and the stock plugin binds ok, though can't do websockets.

I have a Spring application that's being built by gradle (only reason I'm using Gretty is because I need websockets, and the Jetty version in the default plugin is ancient by the looks of it), my appserver gradle file looks like the generic one from the gretty config docs

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

gretty{
    port = 8080
    contextPath = '/app'
    servletContainer = 'jetty8'
}
```

The main build.gradle file is pretty stock standard, pretty much just declaring my dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'scala'

group = 'com.app'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

description = """app"""

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.+'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.+'
    }
}


repositories {
    maven{
        url "http://repo.spring.io/release"
    }
    maven{
        url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.1.+'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version:'2.1.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version:'4.0.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-messaging', version:'4.0.+'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4', version:'2.1.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version:'4.0.+'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version:'4.3.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version:'1.10.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version:'1.8.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.1.+'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '4.1.+'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.+'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.+'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.10'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'2.0.+'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'4.1.+'
    providedCompile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-web-api', version:'7.0'
}

apply from: 'appserver.gradle'
apply from: 'database.gradle'
```

And the database gradle file contains my Liquibase config. Any advice? I've checked everything, seems to be a unique issue to me. Even tried restarted with no luck

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html). Consider upgrading to something that is supported.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sitting on openjdk at the moment. I'll give the Oracle binaries a go

Comment: Uhm...  I mentioned Jetty (the web server), not Java (the vm)

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, early morning late night.... Had the same issue with that one as well, thought going back to 8 might help. Still, giving Openjdk8 a go to see if it helps

Comment: Alright, think I have it. I'd forgotten to have one of the mount configs in /etc/fstab, jetty 9 is coming up fine now. 

Thanks for the help!